# Add tab to multiple lines in Eclipse XML Editor

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to select multiple lines, hit the tab key and have the lines indented in Eclipse? What is the setting to enable multi-line indenting with the tab key?

Answer (score 3):

a) As in any Eclipse Editor: select the lines you want to indent, press tab

b) If you want to go more advanced than that, enable vertical selections: press `alt + shift + a`, use keyboard or mouse to create a multi-line selection. Anything you type now will apply to all selected lines. (turn this off with `alt + shift + a` as well)

Comment: Selecting multiple lines and indenting them with tab doens't seem to work in the Eclipse Java EE XML editor when editing a pom.xml file.

Comment: Selecting multiple lines and indenting them with tab doens't seem to work in the Eclipse Java EE XML editor when editing a pom.xml file.

Comment: @Altoid I just tried it, it works both with the m2e pom editor and with the xml editor (but of course only in the source view)